# Neo4j All Function with break statement / Print Nodes in path upto a certain condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to write the cypher where I want to print the nodes in the path upto certain node. After the certain node, I do not want to compare & print the nodes.

E.g

```
D{type:"fresh"} ---childOf--->C{type:"dirty"}----childOf---->B{type:"fresh"}-----childOf----->A{type:"fresh"}

G{type:"fresh"} ---childOf--->F{type:"fresh"}----childOf---->E{type:"dirty"}-----childOf----->A{type:"fresh"}
```

A is root.

a)

I want o/p such that as soon as I get the dirty node in any list, I want to stop compare & My o/p is path till dirty node. So in this case o/p is

```
c->B->A
```

&

```
E->A
```

D is removed as C is dirty
F & G is removed as E is dirty.

b) In second case, I also do not want the dirty node, so o/p changes to

```
B->A
```

&
    A

**Note** : In both the cases, Root can be dirty & still o/p should remain the same. So In other words, so it does not matter the type of root. O/p is independent on type of root.

Comment: What labels are you using, and do you have the ability to use a :Dirty label instead of a property?

Comment: currently i am using entity as label nd i cant have dirty as label coz i hv mentioned jst one conditipn above but actually i hv more than once.(type & sub_type)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish what you want (stopping the traversal when you hit this property while ignoring the start node) out-of-box with Cypher. All solutions I know of will go beyond the "dirty" nodes and will need to be filtered, which may work for you, in that they'll give the right answer, even if the traversal isn't the most efficient.

Assuming you're using :Node as your label, and using the letters as your name properties, and you have an index on :Node(name) for quick lookup of your start node, this query should work:

```
MATCH path=(:Node{name:'A'})<-[:childOf*]-({type:'dirty'})
WITH path
WHERE single(node in tail(nodes(path)) WHERE node.type = 'dirty')
RETURN nodes(path)[..-1] as nodes
```

If you have the option to use a :Dirty label instead of the property, then there's a way to do this with APOC Procedures, stopping traversal as soon as we hit a node with the label in question.